# similar matrices, similar polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, similar-matrices

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and $p \in \mathbb{K}[X]$ a polynomial.

If $A,B \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$ are similar, $p(A)$ and $p(B)$ are also similar

my attempt:

$A=S^{-1}BS$
$S,T\in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$

$p(B) = \sum^{n}_{i=0} a_i B^i$
$p(A)= \sum^{n}_{i=0} a_i(S^{-1}BS)^i$

$p(A) = T^{-1}p(B)T$

$\sum^{n}_{i=0} a_i(S^{-1}BS)^i = T^{-1} (\sum^{n}_{i=0} a_i B^i )T$

Im not sure how to solve this or if Im even on the right track

Comment: What does it mean for polynomials to be similar? Are you just wanting to show that the **matrices** $p(A)$ and $p(B)$ are similar? That should be very straightforward to prove (and looks like you have it). If anything you have a few extra details that you don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

This is a consequence of the identity

$$p(A) = p(S^{-1} B S) = S^{-1} p(B) S$$ which is easy to verify due to linearity and the equality

$$(S^{-1} B S)^n = \underbrace{(S^{-1} B S) \dots (S^{-1} B S)}_{n \text{ times}} = S^{-1} B^n S$$ valid for all $n \in \mathbb N$.